# How to find elements whose id has prefix "Translations_"?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html

```
<details data-level="2" open="">
    <details data-level="5" open="">
        <summary class="section-heading">
            <h5 id="Translations">Translations</h5>
        </summary>
    </details>
    <details data-level="5" open="">
        <summary class="section-heading">
            <h5 id="Translations_2">Translations</h5>
        </summary>
    </details>
    <details data-level="5" open="">
        <summary class="section-heading">
            <h5 id="Translations_6">Translations</h5>
        </summary>
    </details>
</details>
```

I would like to extract such elements which are signified by `Translation`

```
<h5 id="Translations">Translations</h5>
<h5 id="Translations_2">Translations</h5>
<h5 id="Translations_6">Translations</h5>
```

With `soup.select('details[data-level] > summary[class] > h5[id="Translations"]')`, I'm able to extract only the first element. Could you please explain how to modify my code to do so?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

texte = """
<details data-level="2" open="">
    <details data-level="5" open="">
        <summary class="section-heading">
            <h5 id="Translations">Translations</h5>
        </summary>
    </details>
    <details data-level="5" open="">
        <summary class="section-heading">
            <h5 id="Translations_2">Translations</h5>
        </summary>
    </details>
    <details data-level="5" open="">
        <summary class="section-heading">
            <h5 id="Translations_6">Translations</h5>
        </summary>
    </details>
</details>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(texte, 'html.parser')
soup.select('details[data-level] > summary[class] > h5[id="Translations"]')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`attr^=value` CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

> Represents elements with an attribute name of attr whose value is
> prefixed (preceded) by value.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''\
<details data-level="2" open="">
    <details data-level="5" open="">
        <summary class="section-heading">
            <h5 id="Translations">Translations</h5>
        </summary>
    </details>
    <details data-level="5" open="">
        <summary class="section-heading">
            <h5 id="Translations_2">Translations</h5>
        </summary>
    </details>
    <details data-level="5" open="">
        <summary class="section-heading">
            <h5 id="Translations_6">Translations</h5>
        </summary>
    </details>
</details>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for e in soup.select('h5[id^=Translations]'):
    print(e)
```